# After Dual-Boot, Starting Ubuntu Ends At Purple Screen

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I recently dual-booted my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7. However, every time I try to start Ubuntu from Grub, it ends at a purple screen and the fan kicks on high. This is also the case when going into Recovery Mode. Windows, however, boots up fine. I did the same installation process on my desktop with no issues, however; can boot into both easily. The major difference between the two systems is that my laptop had Windows 8 pre-installed with EFI. I presume this had something to do with it. Though, I have turned secure boot off and made sure (as far as I know) it wasn't installing in EFI mode when I did the Windows 7 and 14.04 installations.

I looked this up on Google and these forums, tried a variety of things:

```
- boot-repair (which seemed to make things way worse)
- reinstalled Ubuntu to no avail
- checked FSTAB
- updated drivers through CHROOT in Live USB
- reinstalled Grub
- NOMODESET
- and wiped the GPT with fixdisk.
```

Wondering if anyone has any ideas on something else to try.

Comment: Boot repair should have asked you to purge and reinstall GRUB. Since you can see the purple, I'm guessing correctly installed the bootloader. Now, you should probably grab a live-CD and run `e2fsck -pcfvkDC 0 /dev/sdaX`. You may even want to boot into a GRUB command prompt and boot from there (see [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Encountering_the_dreaded_GRUB_2_boot_prompt)) or at least remove `quiet splash` to see where it's messing up.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I will attempt these and report back.  Oh, on a side note... removing quiet splash does nothing.  Just the same purple screen for whatever reason.

Comment: Huh, could be a grub problem then. I strongly suggest you try booting from the grub prompt then.

Comment: The first command didn't seem to do anything other than freeze up Terminal.  However, booting from Grub's command prompt shows that it locks up when initializing RAM disk.  That's progress though!

Comment: The first command takes a while. Like.. thirty minutes for me. Maybe more depending on your disk usage. Now, you probably want to run memory checks. You can schedule one from inside Windows.

Comment: Six years later... yep, memory test was completely fine.